# Entering Ctrl-; seems to enter ^[ (escape) in WSL2/Ubuntu/Windows Terminal. How to turn off?

Tags: ubuntu, wsl2, windows-terminal

Entering `Ctrl-;` (control with semicolon) seems to enter `^[` (escape) in WSL2/Ubuntu/Windows Terminal.  Why is this happening, and how do I turn off this behavior?

Note that it doesn't seem to happen when I start up xterm from the Windows Terminal (using VcXsrv).  Also, entering `Ctrl-;` in a Windows Terminal PowerShell tab seems to make a semicolon appear on the screen (I assume that's all it's doing there but I'm not sure).

Windows Terminal
Version: 1.17.11461.0

Comment: I have the same behavior over SSH, and also using cmd in wt. `showkey -a` shows pressing escape: `^D    4 0004 0x04`. Using the normal cmd terminal and ssh eats `Ctrl+;` entirely... (`showkey -a` shows nothing). My guess is a bug with OpenSSH for windows? If you just want to stop it from sending escape, you could remap `Ctrl+;` to an action like "scroll down" in the microsoft terminal settings which will eat the input instead. Might be worth creating an issue here https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues or in their bugzilla

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're seeing is https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3483. The Windows Console (and by extension, the Terminal) currently have a bug with certain key chords, including <kbd>ctrl+;</kbd>.